# Is it possible to route all URLs with dashes in FuelPHP?

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

In the following configuration is it possible to use a regular expression or any other method besides specifing each route to use controller `thisisatest` when URL is `this-is-a-test/action`? Would I have to build/extend my own Router class?

```
<?php
return array(
    '_root_'  => 'home/index',  // The default route
    '_404_'   => 'error/404',    // The main 404 route

    //'hello(/:name)?' => array('welcome/hello', 'name' => 'hello')
);

/* end of config/routes.php */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I implemented this was to extend `\Fuel\Core\Router` using the following. The router class works with a URI which has been passed through the methods in `security.uri_filter` from `config.php` so rather than modifying the router class methods I had my router extension add a callback to that array.

```
class Router extends \Fuel\Core\Router
{
    public static function _init()
    {   
        \Config::set('security.uri_filter', array_merge(
            \Config::get('security.uri_filter'),
            array('\Router::hyphens_to_underscores')
        ));
    }

    public static function hyphens_to_underscores($uri)
    {
        return str_replace('-', '_', $uri);
    }
}
```

You could just as easily add it straight to the configuration array in `app/config/config.php` by way of a closure or a call to a class method or a function.

The downside of this is that both /path_to_controller/action and /path-to-controller/action will work and possibly cause some duplicate content SEO problems unless you indicate this to the search spider. This is assuming both paths are referenced somewhere i.e. a sitemap or an `<a href="">` etc.

Comment: To comment on your "downside". Unless I'm mistaken, the spider wouldn't know of `/path_to_controller/action` (with underscore) unless there is a link to it or in the sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the router class does not have the functionality by default. You would indeed need to extend or create your own router class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the security.uri_filter config setting for that.

Create a function that converts hyphens to underscores, and you're done. You don't need to extend the router class for it. Just supply the function name (wether in a class or a function defined in the bootstrap) to the config, and you're off.

Comment: Interesting... will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's after the event, but this is for anyone else wanting this in future...

In order to avoid confusion between underscores and sub-folders I preferred to convert hyphens to camel-case, so routing URL `this-is-a-test` to class `Controller_ThisIsATest`.

I did this (in FuelPHP 1.4) by adding an anonymous function to the ‘uri_filter’ in the ‘security’ settings in `fuel/app/config/config.php`:

```
'security' => array(
    'uri_filter' => array('htmlentities',
        function($uri) { 
            return str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $uri))); 
        }),
),
```